# Finding maximum and minimum (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I want to write an assembly program to find the maximum and minimum values for a given set of numbers.

Here is my last attempt

```
[ORG 0x100] 

jmp start

start: mov ax,0
       mov bx,0

again: mov  ax,[num+bx]
       add  bx,2
       cmp  bx,18
       mov  [max],ax
       cmp  ax,[max]
       jl   max_pre
       mov  [max], ax
       mov  [min],ax
       cmp  ax,[min]
       jg   min_pre
       jne again    

max_pre: mov [max],ax

min_pre: mov [min],ax   

num: dw 56 , 45, 36 , 67 , 76 , 22 , 89 , 12 , 29 , 83
min: dw 56
max: dw 56

end: mov    ax, 0x4c00  ;terminate program
int     0x21
```

Comment: If this is your last attempt then this is a fail. For example, what  do you suppose will happen after the instruction at `min_pre:` has executed?

Comment: I should provide a jump instruction ?

Comment: For example, yes. You can't have control flow going into the data table.

Comment: What we did in the lab is providing a jump instruction to end the execution of the program: jl end

Comment: `mov  [max],ax` directly followed by `cmp  ax,[max]` doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If you compare something against itself the result will always be equal.